# How can I store my outcome into an array in ruby language?

Tags: ruby

My teacher asked me to write a Ruby program that  contain a loop and in each iteration it randomly makes a choice: head (represented by 1) or tail (represented by 0), and stores the outcome (0 or 1) in an array. I am not sure how to store my outcome into an array and this is my code

```
p "Select a number between 50 to 100"
    x = gets.to_i
    i = 0
    array[x]
    while i < x
     a = rand(0..1)
     array.push(a)
     i += 1
    end
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work except for the `array[x]` line ... you don't initialize arrays with length in ruby. Use `array = []` instead.

Comment: To elaborate further. Ruby uses dynamic arrays by default, so there is no need to provide specify the length up front. I recommend taking a look at the [*Array* documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html). Here you find examples on how to create and modify an array. It also shows how to add items and iterate over them. You don't need to read the full page, just scroll over the introduction and filter out what you need.

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Hay, may you can try the following:

```
number_of_times = gets.to_i
array = []
number_of_times.times do 
  random_result = rand(0..1)
  array.push(random_result)
end
```

or (like the comments)

```
n = gets.to_i
array = n.times.map{ rand(0..1) }
```

After executing this, `array` will have the result of all randomized options.

**Note1**: You don't need to initialize array with the width, you can just initialize the array and push elements to him.

**Note2**: No problems with your `while` operator, but in ruby, you have the `.times` iterator, is more legible for this case.

Comment: Even just `x.times.map { rand(0..1) }`

Comment: `Array.new(x){ rand(2) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Ruby's `Array` block constructor to allocate and initialize your array in a one-liner:

```
array = Array.new(n) { rand(0..1) }  # sample result: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] for n = 6
```

The argument `n` determines the `size` of the array, and the block argument is used to initialize each of the `n` elements.